# How many different ways of displaying prints

Tags: combinatorics

Magda has 6 different prints that she wants to hang on her bedroom wall, but she has room to hang only 2 of them. In how many different ways can she display the prints on her wall?

I tried $6 \times 5=30$

Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right.

In a more general point of view if she has to pick k amoung n element she has : $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ possibilities.

In our case it's $\frac{6!}{(6-2)!} = \frac{6!}{4!} = 6*5$

You can also see that as :
to choose the first one she has n possibilities,
to choose the 2nd one she has n-1 possibilities because she has allready chosen one
...
to choose the kth one she has n-(k-1) possibilities because she has allready chosen k-1
So she has $n*(n-1)*\dots*(n-k+1)$ possibilities

As mentionned by Travis in a comment, it's only if the order is important, if not you have to divided all the possibilities by the number of k-permutations, so $k!$, to get rid of doubles solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct more generally if she has n prints and k hanging spots this is

## =n! /(n-k)!

If the order doesn't  matters divide by k!